# Sending large xml as body in request module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, request

I have a very large xml which gets generated using wsjs node module. it looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                                                xmlns:diag="http://diagnostic.ws.fcrewards.test.com/" xmlns:ws="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><soapenv:Header><ws:Action>http://diagnostic.ws.fcrewards.test.com/doEcho</ws:Action><ws:To>https://ws.mastercard.com/mtf/MRS/DiagnosticService</ws:To><ws:MessageID>35b479f1-5a54-e9a4-5551-0f15507f54b8</ws:MessageID><ws:ReplyTo><ws:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/role/anonymous</ws:Address></ws:ReplyTo><o:Security><u:Timestamp wsu:Id="_0" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><u:Created>2017-02-24T17:13:13Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2017-02-24T17:18:13Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" u:Id="sec_0">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</o:BinarySecurityToken><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI="#_0"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>qNgtbxFDtGr1QCRG4ZnGSzfWqQ+GZJkuQAHgTxcI4B8=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>ZqHJTwD91tcddddddddd3uZkuChVE0BHEx55YF3kGNw1D55VbunmbNZkmxxkuBvyAMjns/DJ8/duThXhlAmyPLYhRgj4djz8smJbksago1Tb+DFT8RQ4tOVPD2TPSaC5wrwA9g9zCCpPDHHv5FmZ4TIxwkPjG37MBqOIgUF8cUkL9kXU0sIJrUQddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwsRtcjKDksvWpMBj0oSysWi+8/ce2HnO4nOuhrvX66BDOAyPL+avL2+JNTlA==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference URI="#sec_0" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature></o:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><diag:doEcho>Cieran</diag:doEcho></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

when I send this request using request module of node.js

```
request.post({
        url: ctx.url,
        body: ctx.request,
        headers: {
            "SOAPAction": ctx.action,
            "Content-Type": ctx.contentType,
            "ContentLength": Buffer.byteLength(ctx.request),
            "MIME-Version": "1.0",
            "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
            "AcceptEncoding": "gzip"
        },
        encoding: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        agentOptions: ctx.agentOptions
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        ctx.response = body
        if (response) {
            ctx.resp_headers = response.headers
            ctx.resp_contentType = response.headers["content-type"]
        }
        if (error) ctx.error = error
        else ctx.statusCode = response.statusCode
        callback(ctx)
    })
```

ctx.request has the whole xml in it as 1 big string
I always get Authorization failed error because endpoint is out rightly rejecting my request.
But if I take the xml and put it in SOAPUI and do format xml then I get the right result.
So I concluded that since i'm sending the body as 1 big xml the endpoint doesn't like my request.
What's the workaround for this?
Is there any other node module available which can format the xml or break it up in small strings?